# Will the Uno bootloader work in the Duemilanove?

Tags: arduino-uno, bootloader, arduino-duemilanove

I had an old duemilanove lying around (Which was not working because i accidentially busted the atmega) and I recently bought some atmegas pre-flashed with the UNO bootloader. So I tried to put one of those in it, and it seems to work fine except that I have to select the UNO board in the arduino IDE.

My question is: Is there anything problematic to be aware of when using the UNO bootloader in an duemilanove?

Answer (score 3):

So I researched it a bit, and there does not seem to be any problems with running the UNO bootloader on a Duemilanove board.

The biggest difference between the two seems to be the USB interface:

**USB interface**

Duemilanove uses FTDI, UNO uses another microcontroller (ATmega8u2).

Since the USB to serial is transparent for me as an end user for the most parts, it doesn't really matter to me.

**Leaner bootloader**

The UNO bootloader is smaller than the duemilanove.